# Set focus on recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I really want to set focus on a specific RecyclerView item.
I tried

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(1);
```

in my initializeRecyclerView method. I tried also

```
holder.setSelected(selectedItem==position)
```

without success.

Can you please help me ?

Here is my Adapter:

```
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.radio_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

/**
 * Set the properties of a RecyclerView item
 * @param holder RecyclerView item
 * @param position Position of the item in the items list
 */
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Radio radio = radios.get(position);
    holder.radio = radio;
    ImageHelper.setImage(context, holder.imageButton, radio.getLogoPath(), context.getDrawable(Const.DEFAULT_RADIO_LOGO_DRAWABLE) );
    holder.imageButton.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
    holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(clickListener != null){
                clickListener.onRadioClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    });
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private ImageButton imageButton;
    public Radio radio;

    private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    }
}
```

And in my Fragment:

```
if(getView()!=null){
        RadiosAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RadiosAdapter(radios, getActivity());
        RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.radios_recycler);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), columnNumber, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        if(currentRadio !=null){
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(currentRadio.getPosition());
        }
        else{
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(1);
        }

        if(getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof OnClickListener){
            OnClickListener listener = (OnClickListener)getActivity();
            recyclerAdapter.setClickListener(listener);
        }
    }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

using `requestFocus()` might solve your problem.
but if not, I solved the same kind of a problem via,

in `adapter` I override the `OnViewAttachedToWindow()` and in there I called `requestFocus()` when ViewHolder is the matching the item.

Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41232962/7616455

Answer (score 0):

Also calling inside onBindViewHolder works for me, for example if you want focus the first item.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PodcastTvViewHolder, position: Int){
    if (position == 0) holder.itemView.requestFocus()
}
```